# My Dell XPS 13 9360 will take a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04 in UEFI mode no problem. For a few days. Then I get a kernel panic, not syncing:

Tags: boot

This has happened 4 times now, exit code=0x00000000. It simply won’t boot and I am forced into doing a reinstall, again, and again. Any ideas? I have done extensive testing of the system including memory and everything ‘seems’ ok.

Comment: Would you please provide a screenshot of this kernel panic?

Answer (score 0):

First thank you for replying. After all manner of grub and grub2 repair attempts, memory test, cpu and assorted hardware test I finally just swapped out the 128Gb drive with a 500gb samsung drive. So far all is well, at least it reboots now. I can only surmise that the little drive just didnt have enough room with all the temp stuff the power saving features employ. So on the reinstall from scratch on the new drive I turned off all the power saving related switches while on AC. The LogitechMX Anywhere3 mouse still has issues with the buttons working, then they dont but the cursor moves around the screen. So you turn it off and back on and all is ok? So at this point I would call it 'fixed'.